# Issue on Bootstrap Image Position Absolute in .well Class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to put an image with absolute position inside a .well div. I have to keep the image position absolute as I would like to create a responsive image using following CSS format. But the image appears out of the div scope.Here are my code for html and css

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
      <img  class="img-polaroid" src="http://testimage.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

.css

```
img{
     position: absolute;
     max-width: 80%;
     top: 10%;
     left: 10%;
}
```

As you can see I cant change the position property to 'relative'. I also tried to add a height:auto; property to .well class but it didn't go through neither.

Comment: Depending on how you want the image to show up, negative margins may help. Setting a relative x-position of 50% and a margin of -(width/2), you can "center" block elements.

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a need for absolute positioning, you're using percentages which are relative units to the containing element. So therefore if your `<img>` tag is inside of the div then it's percentage width or height, let's say 50% will always be 50% the height or width of the `<div>` (this is presuming that the `<div>` is fluid).

Max-width is a good thing to be using.

Another technique for scenarios requiring finer tuning is to figure out the dimensions of the image and compare it to the size of the page. Let's say an image is 500 X 100 and the page width is 1200px wide document. The calculation to find out the percentage is (500 / 1200 ) × 100 = 41.66%

This is why in the Bootstrap.css file all widths are given in percentage.

Hope I've explained it all a bit to you.